# jqgrid pagination with SQL Server

Tags: jquery, sql-server-2008

My jqgrids are working with my sorting features but I am returning up to 1000 records, which is a dog on performance. So I would like to add paging to the stored procedures (SQL Server 2008) but don't know how to go about accomplishing this. Would someone have an example of how I would need to write the stored procedure to accommodate parameters for what page I am on or how many rows are selected. Or do I just pass all the records and then somehow configure the jqgrid to figure out the paging and rows?

Comment: Have you tried **searching** yourself? [Tons of hits on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+2008+stored+procedure+paging)

Comment: Thanks, my searching here has not given me these results before

Answer (score 0):

SET @SQL = 'DECLARE @FirstRegistry INT, @LastRegistry INT SET @FirstRegistry = ' + CAST (@Page AS NVARCHAR(1000))
+ ' SET @LastRegistry = ' + CAST(@RegistriesPerPage AS NVARCHAR(1000))
SET @SQL = @SQL +'SELECT *  FROM Employee c,DEPT cc LEFT OUTER JOIN Section ru
SET @SQL = @SQL + @CRT +
    ' SELECT * FROM #TEMPTABLE  WHERE Counter between    ((@LastRegistry -1) * @FirstRegistry + 1) AND 
     (((( @LastRegistry -1)* @FirstRegistry +1) + @FirstRegistry ) -1 )'

Comment: Set @RegistriesPerPage=@resultCount -- Number of records to return
Set @Page=@resultIndex -- Start Record Number